# How to read/edit a .DOCX file in android SD Card using OpenXML4J or DOCX4J

Tags: android, xml, docx4j

I read in some blog post that OpenXML4J have a Android Library for reading .DOCX file in Android and with help of that we can easily edit, read and create DOCX format.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. Using same code as I use in OpenXML4J will create DOCX? Is there a library in DocX4j for android?

Comment: If you've read this in a blog post, have you tried following the instructions that were mentioned there? Also, afaik, you can use any java library in an Android development project, with the warning about 'size matters' firmly in mind.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience I am pretty sure this should be all possible. And you do not need an android specific jar a regular one works fine since its the same java working on it